# Java 8 Stream#collect vs. Spark PairRDDFunctions#combineByKey

Tags: apache-spark, java-8

I am new to Java 8 and Stream API, and I am exercising it.

I am using the following code to compute the maximum value of the collection, Looks that I have coded correctly.

```
@Test
public void testStreamCollect() {
    List<Integer> data = Arrays.asList(1, 22, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 31, 8, 10, 17, 52, 2, 3, 48, 11);
    Stream<Integer> stream = data.parallelStream();
    Supplier<AtomicInteger> createCombiner = () -> {
        AtomicInteger initial = new AtomicInteger();
        initial.set(Integer.MIN_VALUE);
        return initial;
    };
    BiConsumer<AtomicInteger, Integer> mergeValue = (accum, ii) -> {
        if (ii > accum.get()) {
            accum.set(ii);
        }
    };

    BiConsumer<AtomicInteger, AtomicInteger> mergeCombiner = (a, b) -> {
        if (a.get() < b.get()) {
            a.set(b.get());
        }
    };
    AtomicInteger max = stream.collect(createCombiner, mergeValue, mergeCombiner);
    System.out.println(max);
}
```

What I would ask is: the Stream#collect method has three arguments, I name them as `createCombiner, mergeValue and mergeCombiner,`

I name so because it looks to me that Stream#collect is very similar to Spark `PairRDDFunctions#combineByKey` method, which also has the `createCombiner,mergeValue,mergeCombiners function as the arguments,it full signature

```
def combineByKeyWithClassTag[C](
      createCombiner: V => C,
      mergeValue: (C, V) => C,
      mergeCombiners: (C, C) => C,
      partitioner: Partitioner,
      mapSideCombine: Boolean = true,
      serializer: Serializer = null)(implicit ct: ClassTag[C]): RDD[(K, C)]
```

If they are the same/similar in functionality, I would conclude that Stream#collect is used for parallel programming within one process, maybe the underlying support framework is Java fork/join framework.It works in the following four steps:

1. Split the problem into several parts that can be executed in a parallel fashion
2. For each part, initialize a mutable container to hold the partial result.
3. For each element in the part, merge it into the container created in the 2nd step.
4. The last step, merge the containers from all the parts, and the merged result container will be the result of collect method

Not sure I have understood correctly.

Comment: As a side note, you don’t need a thread safe container like `AtomicInteger` for  `Stream.collect(…)`, as the way, these three functions are used, ensures that a container is never accessed by more than one thread at a time. So you could also have used `int max = data.parallelStream().collect(()->new int[]{Integer.MIN_VALUE}, (a,i)->{if(i>a[0]) a[0]=i;}, (a,b)->{if(a[0]<b[0]) a[0]=b[0];})[0];` instead.

Comment: Thanks @holger, just as you are using an array, I am using AtomicInteger as a container that can change the value in it.

Comment: Yes, using an `AtomicInteger` or an array is semantically the same. But `AtomicInteger` is thread safe and this safety comes with an overhead that is not necessary here. Just saying.

Comment: Thanks @holger，I agree with you. The AtomicInteger involves CAS and volatile that assures memory visibility

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java Streams can be processed in parallel - they have `parallel` method. However, it's still one-machine processing.

Basically your understanding is ok. Create Combiner returns mutable result, Merge Values defines how to add partial results/elements of the stream to the mutable result and Merge Combiners merges few combiners' mutable results into one result.

Some names are different, here's the explanation:

- Spark's Create Combiner = Stream's Supplier
- Spark's Merge Values = Stream's Accumulator - accumulation means just some way of merging few results
- Spark's Merge Combiners = Stream's Combiner - for Spark combiner is the MergeValues function, however Merging Combiners means the same as Stream's Combiner

Combiner in Spark is the same mutable result container as Stream's Container

Spark's processing is done in parallel and across multiple machines. On one machine the semantics are the same (or looks like the same - implementation details can be different), however Streams can't be processed on cluster.1

Comment: Thanks @t-gawęda for the answer. yes, I am aware of the fact that Java-8 Streams API can only be parallel within one process(The fork/join framework also applies to one process), while Spark can be parallel across processes(It is a distributed computing framework)